# Fetching data with filters in django ORM

Tags: python, django, django-orm

I have `Sport` object which has many `Source` objects which in turn has many `Feed` objects. Each `Feed` object has a published time.

```
class Sport(Base):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255, unique=True)

class Source(Base):
    name = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255)
    sport = models.ForeignKey(Sport, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)

class Feed(Base):
    title = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255)
    link = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=255, unique=True)
    summary = models.TextField()
    published = models.DateTimeField()
    source = models.ForeignKey(Source, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
```

If I want to get all Feeds in the reverse chronology of published time where source has sport A, 20 at a time. I'm not sure how to do this with django ORM. Can someone help me with this query.

Comment: are there supposed to be relations between your models (signalled by `ForeignKey` or `ManyToManyField` fields)? It sounds from your text that there should be, but none are shown in your code. Without these it is impossible to get the models to interact with each other.

Comment: and what is the `Base` class? Django models need to inherit from `django.db.models.Model`

Comment: @RobinZigmond the models have one to many relationship not many to many. Base is just a meta class with created and modified time. I've updated my code.

Comment: Thanks for the update, the relationships are now clear. Assuming `Base` does indeed inherit from Django's `model` class, then if I'm understanding your intentions correctly you need to do (I'm assuming the relevant Sport object has `name` value of `"A"`): `Feed.objects.filter(source__sport__name="A").order_by("-published")`. That will give you all such objects, not 20 at a time - but to get a particular batch of 20 you can just slice it using the normal Python syntax for slicing lists. (I'd recommend you read or reread the guide here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/ )

Comment: @RobinZigmond You should post that as an answer.